# Linearlayout textview background issue

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, textview

I want to set below `layout`

[image]

Below is my xml code:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"  
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_steps"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txt_titl"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:weightSum="100"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_step_1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="33"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_15"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/grystep1"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
            android:textColor="#626262"
            android:layout_below="@+id/icon_flag"
            android:text="STEP - 1"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_step_2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="33"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_15"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-10dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/grystep2"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                android:textColor="#626262"
                android:layout_below="@+id/icon_flag"
                android:text="STEP - 2"/>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_step_3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="33"
            android:background="@drawable/grystep3"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_15"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
            android:textColor="#626262"
            android:layout_below="@+id/icon_flag"
            android:text="STEP - 3"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

when I run above code I get below image layout

[image]

i don't know why space is coming  any idea how can i solve this problem? Your suggestions are appreciated

***EDIT***

[image]

Layout FILE

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_steps"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txt_titl"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:weightSum="100"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_step_1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="33"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_15"
         android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/grystep1"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
         android:textColor="#626262"
        android:layout_below="@+id/icon_flag"
        android:text="STEP - 1"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_step_2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-11dp"
            android:layout_weight="33"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_15"
             android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/grystep2"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
             android:textColor="#626262"
            android:layout_below="@+id/icon_flag"
            android:text="STEP - 2"/>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_step_3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-12dp"

        android:layout_weight="33"
        android:background="@drawable/grystep3"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_15"
         android:gravity="center"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
         android:textColor="#626262"
        android:layout_below="@+id/icon_flag"
        android:text="STEP - 3"/>
   </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: remove all padding and margin

Comment: user3676184 : i remove padding and margin form textview but still same issue comes

Comment: @user3676184 that wont solve the problem becaouse of the `triangle shaped` right side. You have to take out `LinearLayout` and play with `negative margin` and padding to achieve what you want.

Comment: Note, that `android:layout_below` parameters in the `TextView`s are useless, because they are in a `LinearLayout`.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

each view in linear layout taking space showing in image so its correct try to give negative left margin  say -10dp to 2nd and 3rd view in linear layout till looks correct

Comment: Narendra Kothamire : as per your suggestion i get layout like my edit portion see my edit portion

Comment: So whats problem you are having now

Comment: i need perfect match all images as per my question i mention top